# Why :help ignore :set number in .vimrc?

Tags: vim, ubuntu-12.04

I `:set number` in `~/.vimrc` to show line numbers. When I type `:help` to view documentation, the line numbers don't show in the new window.

If I type `:setl number?`, it prints `nonumber`. If type `:setg number?`, it prints `number`.

I want to know why `~/.vimrc` doesn't work.  Which script resets the local `number` option?
I've checked the `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/help.vim`, but it doesn't reset the `number`.

---

Currently, I'm using:

```
if has('autocmd')
    auto FileType help set number
endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: interesting. `verbose se nu?` doesn't tell me anything either. It seems hardcoded. What's wrong with the autocmd though? That works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the problem you're having. Numbers don't show up in help - yes, if I recall correctly that is a design decision and a feature - a good one, in my opinion, since why would one want line numbers in help files? (Okey, you could say "to quote a particular line from help file" but tags seems sufficient for that).

As far as the other thing go, when I set

```
 setl nonumber
 setg number
```

and open a new buffer in a split, numbers show.

If I start a new vim session, `setlocal` and `setglobal number` being `nonumber` and `set number` they're both changed.

Is this the behaviour you're having too?

Answer (score 1):

After opening vim, simply type:

```
:auto FileType
```

Do you see `set number` listed under `help`? If not, your .vimrc is not being read.